# Choosing the right exception type when custom attribute is missing

Tags: .net, exception, custom-attributes

I have some trouble for choosing **the right type of exception to throw** when an expected custom attribute is not found (I would prefer one of the existing .NET exceptions).

What do you recommend in this case? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Here his the context:

```
[<ExpectedAttribute()>]
let foo args ... = ...
```

The function `foo` (which is user-defined) is passed to a runtime engine. The runtime have to throw an exception if the custom attribute is not present.

Comment: Please give more context - where is the exception going to be thrown? Is it related to an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a ***custom*** attribute is missing, it is not going to fit a `System` exception.

You could use a System exception, but what is your domain here? And what sort of contract is broken? It matters if this is about serialization or testing or ...

---

Edit, after your `foo` addition: The closest you come with the System exceptions is System.ArgumentException , because your engine is receiving a parameter that does not meet its requirements.

But I would define my own `MissingExpectedAttribute` exception.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something general like "InvalidOperationException" or "InvalidArgumentException" and put the details about the expected attribute in the message.

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` would be appropriate, but `InvalidArgumentException` wouldn't be, `ArgumentException` and subtypes are defined explicitly to be about method argument validation.

Comment: Neither one is specific enough, but you're right, InvalidOperation is a little closer. A custom exception is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor, method or property called was given the rule-breaking object, then ArgumentException. If the rule-breaking object was part of your state from a previous operation, and then the method or property that insists upon this attribute being present was called, the InvalidOperation.